# Get interval of series

Tags: series-expansion

It seems to be a stupid question but I wonder how to get an interval of a series expansion. The current series command

```
Series[f, {x, x0, n}]
```

only give series expansion up to $x^n$, where I want something like

```
Series[f, {x, x0, h, t}]
```

which gives me the series expansion from $x^h$ to $x^t$. Obviously I can get it by doing

```
Series[f, {x, x0, t}] - Series[f, {x, x0, h-1}]
```

However, I believe that it takes longer time than it should take.

Comment: Differencing will give you O[x]^h. You must remove the big O  term to take the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will use the function `Exp[x]` to demonstrate in a simple way how you can do it.

If you try `FullForm[Series[Exp[x], {x, x0, 5}]]` you will get

```
SeriesData[x,x0,List[Power[E,x0], Power[E,x0], Times[ Rational[1,2], Power[E,x0]],
                     Times[ Rational[1,6], Power[E,x0]],Times[ Rational[1,24],Power[E,x0]],
                     Times[ Rational[1,120], Power[E,x0]]],0,6,1]
```

which you can decompose taking parts. Some series as well mentioned by @Michael E2 begin with higher powers and the is stated as a 4th argument in the FullForm (nmin in the code below).

**Update** (thanks @KennyColnago and @Michael E2)

```
seriespart[f_, {x_, x0_, h_, t_}] := Module[{s, nmin},
s = Series[f, {x, x0, t}];
nmin = s[[4]];
s[[3, (h - nmin + 1) ;; (t - nmin + 1)]].Table[(x - x0)^i, {i, h, t}]
]
```

h and t must be positive integers with `t >= h` and `h >= 0`.

So `seriespart` gives

```
seriespart[Exp[x], {x, 1, 5, 9}]

1/120 E (-1 + x)^5 + 1/720 E (-1 + x)^6 + (E (-1 + x)^7)/5040 + 
(E (-1 + x)^8)/40320 + (E (-1 + x)^9)/362880
```

as wanted.

Comment: @Artes thanks for your edit. It is a lot nicer now.

Comment: @Artes yes you are right i had left f[x] instead of just f. I fixed it , thanks. Your method works but it needs adjustment on the lower degree - it doesn't output the x^3 term.

Comment: Are not the powers of `(x-x0)` in `seriespart` one more than they should be? In the `Table` command try `(x-x0)^(i-1)`.

Comment: @KennyColnago , in Loi.Luu's original question he asked the series expansion from `x^h` to `x^t` so i fixed it that way.

Comment: Why do we have h >= 1? Its possible that h = 0  right?

Comment: @Loi.Luu in my solution I took only terms of existing power of x, i.e. x,x^2,x^2,.... and I used the [[3,h;;t]] part. So h must belong to {1,2,3,..,t}. There is not 0 part of an expression (actually this is the header). If you want also the constant term I can adjust my solution above...

Comment: To put KennyCoinago's comment another way, the coefficients in your example do not agree with the coefficients in `Series[Exp[x], {x, 1, 9}]` -- shouldn't they?  Also this gives errors: `seriespart[x^2 Exp[x], {x, 0, 5, 9}]`.

Comment: @Michael E2 you are absolutely right. Updating ASAP

Comment: @KennyColnago thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in`SeriesCoefficient`is useful to give directly the desired expansion coefficient, for not too complicated functions`f[x]`.

```
ExpandSeries[f_, {x0_, h_, t_}] := 
   With[{s=SeriesCoefficient[f, {x, x0, n}, Assumptions :> n>=0], r=Range[h, t]},
        (s /. n -> r).(x - x0)^r]
```

Try

```
Expand[ExpandSeries[x / (1 - x - x^2), {0, 8, 13}]]
```

to see some familiar terms.

Answer (score 3):

*(Updated to handle fractional powers)*

Here's another way to take advantage of [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SeriesData.html).  The data has the format

```
SeriesData[x, x0, {a0, a1,...}, min, max, den]
```

The coefficient `a0` corresponds to the power `(x - x0)^(min/den)`,  `a1` to the power `(x - x0)^((min+1)/den)`, etc.  To get the terms from some point `start`, drop the initial coefficients and change the `min` power.

```
seriesTail[f_, {x_, x0_, start_, end_}] := 
   With[{s = Series[f, {x, x0, end}]}, seriesTail[s, start, end]];
seriesTail[sd : SeriesData[x_, x0_, coeffs_, min_, max_, den_], start_, end_] /;
 start > min/den := 
   SeriesData[x,
              x0,
              Drop[coeffs, Ceiling[start*den - min, den]], 
              min + Ceiling[start*den - min, den],
              max,
              den];
seriesTail[sd_SeriesData, start_, end_] := sd
```

Examples:

```
seriesTail[Exp[x], {x, 0, 5, 9}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
seriesTail[x^6 Exp[x], {x, 0, 5, 9}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
seriesTail[x/(1 - x - x^2), {x, 0, 3, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example (of updated code):

```
seriesTail[Sqrt[x] Exp[x], {x, 0, 5, 9}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you don't want the big-`O` part, use `Normal @ seriesTail[f, {x, x0, start, end}]`.